# Capture Screen with PyQt4 or PySide, except specific widget?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to capture the screen area in the region of my pyqt4 app translucent, but i want exclude the widget "betwn = QPushButton('test')" in the capture, I'm trying to hide the widget using hide() like this: betwn.hide(), for be excluded before the capture, but not works, the "betwn" even hidden anyway is will captured.

Here my PyQt4 Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from datetime import datetime

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def capture():
    p = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId(),widget.geometry().x(),widget.geometry().y(),widget.geometry().width(),widget.geometry().height())
    label.setPixmap(p)
def shoot():
    betwn.hide()
    capture()
    betwn.show()
button = QPushButton('take screenshot', clicked=shoot)
betwn = QPushButton('test')
widget.layout().addWidget(button)
widget.layout().addWidget(betwn)

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here my PySide Code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from datetime import datetime

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def capture():
    p = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId(),widget.geometry().x(),widget.geometry().y(),widget.geometry().width(),widget.geometry().height())
    label.setPixmap(p)
def shoot():
    betwn.hide()
    capture()
    betwn.show()
button = QPushButton('take screenshot', clicked=shoot)
betwn = QPushButton('test')
widget.layout().addWidget(button)
widget.layout().addWidget(betwn)

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

How i can do for exclude the widget "betwn = QPushButton('test')" in the capture? or If you know other way to capture the desktop area using the of the window without capture the window, using the coordinates of the window and the width and height?

Like this:

```
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId(),widget.geometry().x(),widget.geometry().y(),widget.geometry().width(),widget.geometry().height());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the hide method, it does not mean that the button will be closed at that moment, since it involves a repainting process that ends after the synchronous task ends, in these cases you must give adequate time for Qt to do that work and that can be done. make a QTimer::singleShot().

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)


def capture():
    p = QPixmap.grabWindow(
        QApplication.desktop().winId(), 
        *widget.geometry().getRect()
    )
    label.setPixmap(p)
    betwn.show()


def shoot():
    betwn.hide()
    QTimer.singleShot(1, capture)


button = QPushButton("take screenshot", clicked=shoot)
betwn = QPushButton("test")
widget.layout().addWidget(button)
widget.layout().addWidget(betwn)

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc, Can i use Thread(pyqt4 or pyside) insead QTimer.singleShot()?

Comment: @BennyWood No, Qt prohibits interacting directly with the GUI from another thread, and in your case when using QPixmap to record with the GUI you are interacting with the GUI